# detect textbox input from iPad siri

Tags: jquery, ios, siri

I am currently using `keyup` `paste` `propertychange` to detect input into a `textarea` form field.
However when using an iPad with `siri` these properties do not detect text input.

What is the correct way tocapture siri text in a form field using jQuery?

my sample

```
myTxtObj.on("keyup paste propertychange", textBoxTarget, function(e){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Have you tried just `change`?

Comment: i thought `propertychange` was the same thing but you're right `change` did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `change` event in place of (or in addition to) `propertychange`.

Comment: would you recommend replacing or using both?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding documentation on `propertychange` -- it seems to be only [for old IE versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx). In which case, replacing it would be appropriate.

Comment: Change doesn't trigger on input, only when focus is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `input` event. The change event will only detect when you switch focus.

Tested on iPad mini iOS 9.3.1

```
myTxtObj.on('input keyup paste propertychange change', textBoxTarget, function(e) {
    // do something
});
```